# PHP/CSS Logic for distributing differently-sized images in a div

Tags: php, html, css

I'm looking to write some PHP logic to arrange a number of images, of different sizes, within `divs` on a page. The scenarios is this:

I have an array of images (from a MySQL lookup) - anywhere up to 100 images.

The images will be one of a set catalogue of sizes (i.e. 60x40, 120x40, 120x60, or 120x180)

I am arranging the images into `divs` of a set size (120x180).

The logic should work as follows:

Is there enough vertical height in this `div` for this `image` to fit in?
If so, is there enough horizontal width in this line for this `image` to fit?
If there is enough width in this line, then place the image in this line.
If there isn't enough width in this line, then place this image in the next line down.
If there isn't enough vertical height in this `div` for fit this image, then create a new `div`, and place the image at the top of that new `div`.
Repeat this for each image until each image has been placed.

The end result should be number of 120x180 `divs`, each one filled with `images` assorted from 60x40, 120x40, 120x60, or 120x180 in size, with no blank spaces.

How can I code this in PHP?

I started with this, but it (obviously) doesn't work:

```
$pageCount = 1;
$pageWith = 120;
$pageHeight = 180;
echo "<div id='pageFrame' style='width:120px; height:180px;'>";
foreach ($row_ as $Image) {
    // Check Virtical Space on the page
    if($Image['height'] < $pageHeight)
    {
        // Check width on page
        if($Image['width'] < $pageWith)
        {
            echo "<span><img height='".$Image['height']."' width='".$Image['width']."' src='/ite1".$Image['url']."' style='padding:2px;'></span>";
            $pageWith = $pageWith - $Image['width'];
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<br>";
            $pageWith = 120;
            $pageHeight = $pageHeight - $Image['height'];
            echo "<span><img height='".$Image['height']."' width='".$Image['width']."' src='/ite1".$Image['url']."' style='padding:2px;'></span>";
            $pageWith = $pageWith - $Image['width'];
        };
    }
    //If there's no more space on the page because we're at the end of the page, create a new one
    else
    {
        echo "</div id='pageFrame'>";
        echo "<div id='pageFrame' style='width:120px; height:180px;'>";
        $pageHeight = 180;
    };
};
echo "</div id='pageFrame'>";
```

Can you advise?

Comment: I personally would design it in html using bootstrap or similar, then use php to loop and fill in the values. Bootstrap is designed to be responsive, so it has probably already solved your problem.

Comment: Thats a rather complex question. There is first the problem of CSS: you could *maybe* work with `float: left;`. Or maybe use a [grid](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_grid_responsive.asp). Second: working with width and height is not enough in this case. You need some sort of 2 dimensional array. Lets simplify: let's say you have 4x4 size container adding a 3x2 image to it leaves space for another 3x2 image, how do you represent that if you reduce the height and/or width? If you have fixed width sizes then you could use something like bootstrap as @TimMorton mentioned.